# I'm getting below crash in Android 11 OnePlus Device, How to fix this?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-11, oneplusone

Getting application info from package manager leads to app crash, why this has occurred and how to fix it?

Error code

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:641)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.mi.android.globalfileexplorer
   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:428)
   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:417)
 at com.example.mediapicker.ui.FolderListFragment.setMenuItems(FolderListFragment.kt:92)
   at com.example.mediapicker.ui.FolderListFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(FolderListFragment.kt:84)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:3112)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:3212)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:3114)
```

App Code

```
 private fun setMenuItems(apps: MutableList<String>, menu: Menu) {
    menu.clear()
    val pm = requireContext().packageManager
    apps.forEachIndexed { index, packageName ->
        val appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(
            packageName,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
        )
        menu.add(
            0, index, Menu.NONE, pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo)
        ).icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
        if (menu is MenuBuilder) {
            menu.setOptionalIconsVisible(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mediapicker">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MediaPickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_media_picker"
        android:theme="@style/ef_ImagePickerTheme"/>
</application>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*, image/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I'm running the above code in my application and I'm facing this crash in One Plus devices how to fix this?

Comment: `Error code

Caused by android.... ` Ok. Caused by... But you omitted the error/exception. Please post more complete stack trace.

Comment: @blackapps  I have updated the error log

Comment: What also is missing is that you dont show us with which values you call that function. And we have no idea where com.mi.android.globalfileexplorer would come from.

Comment: `val appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(
            packageName,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
        )` from this line it movesto com.mi.android.globalfileexplorer

Comment: @ZeroCool I have the same problem, The image picker not opening on oneplus nord 2 in my app. Have you solved this problem? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int))

> getApplicationInfo Throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException if a
> package with the given name cannot be found on the system.

In your case you are looking for `com.mi.android.globalfileexplorer` which is the Xiaomi file explorer app that is not installed on your OnePlus device.

Handle the exception and avoid adding the item to the menù if thrown.